# Xpath in Google Sheets selecting class error

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

```
=IMPORTXML("https://camelcamelcamel.com/popular","//*[@class='current_price']")
```

I am trying to extract the prices from a list of popular Amazon items on CamelCamelCamel.

I can easily get the item links from the page with this code:

```
=FILTER(IMPORTXML("https://camelcamelcamel.com/popular","//h3/a/@href"),REGEXMATCH(IMPORTXML("https://camelcamelcamel.com/popular","//h3/a/@href"),"/product/"))
```

But I can't seem to get the price no matter what I do. Everything I've tried has failed, specific Xpaths and extremely general like the one above.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get prices with this formula:
`=IMPORTXML("https://camelcamelcamel.com/popular","//div[@class='current_price']")`

The result was unstable and sometimes it showed `N/A`.

After reloading page in some time I've got:

[image]